# How to check whether stream has any data?

Tags: php

This what I'm trying to do:

```
$output = '';
$stream = popen("some-long-running-command 2>&1", 'r');
while (!feof($stream)) {
  $meta = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
  if ($meta['unread_bytes'] > 0) {
    $line = fgets($stream);
    $output .= $line;
  }
  echo ".";
}
$code = pclose($stream);
```

Looks like this code is not correct, since it gets stuck at the call to `stream_get_meta_data()`. What is the right way to check whether the stream has some data to read? The whole point here is to avoid locking at `fgets()`.

Comment: `fgets()` locks because it waits for a "new-line" character. Use `stream_get_contents()` with the length argument instead: `$line = stream_get_contents($stream, $meta['unread_bytes']);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct way to do this is with [`stream_select()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php):

```
$stream = popen("some-long-running-command 2>&1", 'r');
while (!feof($stream)) {
  $r = array($stream);
  $w = $e = NULL;

  if (stream_select($r, $w, $e, 1)) {
    // there is data to be read
  }
}
$code = pclose($stream);
```

One thing to note though (I'm not sure about this) is that it may be the `feof()` check that is "blocking" - it may be that the loop never ends because the child process does not close its STDOUT descriptor.

Comment: It is important to note that, as @DaveRandom has done, if you are going to use NULL you MUST assign it to a variable in order to avoid trouble with passing a non-variable by reference (which is how the first three parameters are declared).  Read the notes at http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-select.php